# hosted Look of the Year

Tags: word-usage

Does "look" here mean "a person's appearance"?

Edit: Ok. I found that "Look of the Year" is a competition.

> Teen models, powerful men and private dinners: when Trump **hosted Look of the Year**
> In the early 90s, Donald Trump judged the world’s biggest modelling competition - since hit by allegations of abuse. This is how the people who were there remember it

> Source: [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/mar/14/teen-models-powerful-men-when-donald-trump-hosted-look-of-the-year)

Comment: If you have an answer, you can self answer or delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is "appearance", in a sense related to the fashion industry:

[Merriam Webster "look"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look)

> (noun)  c : a combination of design features giving a unified appearance
> *a new look in women's fashions*

[American Heritage Dictionary "look"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=look)

> (noun) c. A distinctive, unified manner of dress or fashion:
> *the preferred look for this fall.*